# Passing sobject id values to a apex string throws nothing?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Unable to pass id field to apex.

```
public class update_random_question
{
    public List<Question__c> question_list{get;set;}
    public List<Answer__c> answer_list{get;set;}
    public List<Answer__c> CheckAnswerlist{get;set;}    
    public string idchosen{get;set;}

    public pagereference update_random_question()
    {
        question_list= [SELECT Name,QuestionName__c,orderby__c FROM Question__c];
        for(Question__c q : question_list)
        {
            q.orderby__c = randomizer.getRandomNumber(1000);            
        }
        answer_list= [SELECT Name,QuestionId__c,AnswerName__c,orderby__c FROM Answer__c];
        for(answer__c a : answer_list)
        {
            a.orderby__c = randomizer.getRandomNumber(1000);            
        }
    update question_list;
    update answer_list;

    question_list = [SELECT Id,Name,QuestionName__c,OrderBy__c FROM question__c where iscompleted__c = False order by orderby__c limit 1];

    answer_list = [SELECT QuestionId__c,Name,AnswerName__c,OrderBy__c From Answer__c WHERE QuestionId__c = :question_list[0].Id order by orderby__c];

    return null;
    }

    public void is_answer()
    {
        CheckAnswerlist = [SELECT isanswer__c From Answer__c WHERE id = :idchosen];        
    }
}
```

**Apex:**

```
<apex:page controller="update_random_question">
    <apex:form >

     <apex:Commandbutton Value="Begin" action="{!update_random_question}" reRender="Questions_Block"/>
     <apex:pageBlock title="Questions" Id="Questions_Block" >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!question_list}" var="q">
             <apex:column value="{!q.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!q.QuestionName__c}"/>             
             <apex:column value="{!q.OrderBy__c}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!answer_list}" var="a">
             <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.QuestionID__c}"/>             
             <apex:column>
              <apex:commandLink value="{!a.AnswerName__c}" action="{!is_answer}" reRender="CheckAnswer" />
                  <apex:param value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!idchosen}" />
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!a.OrderBy__c}"/>             
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>

     <apex:pageBlock id="CheckAnswer">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CheckAnswerlist}" var="an">
              <apex:column value="{!an.isanswer__c}"/>
          </apex:pageblockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>     
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As strange as it seems you need to add a name attribute to the param and put the param inside the command link:

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!a.AnswerName__c}" action="{!is_answer}" reRender="CheckAnswer" >    
     <apex:param name="idParam" value="{!a.id}" assignTo="{!idchosen}" />
</apex:commandLink>
```

*Name* being there may or may not help but I seem to recall without it it did not work as expected. At the very least it must be within the command link tag

You should also check to ensure the value is set before using it:

```
public void is_answer()
    {
        if(string.isBlank(idchosen))
           //throw some error to create a page message
        CheckAnswerlist = [SELECT isanswer__c From Answer__c WHERE id = :idchosen];        
    }
```